# How can I make my outputs cycle up or down to the final answer?

Tags: javascript, html, time

I've got a simple simulator code where the user selects buttons to vary the inputs, and the outputs change in response (an example extract of which is shown below).

However, the outputs update automatically to the solution, and I was wondering if there's a way to show the numbers ticking over and increasing from what was previously displayed to the new number?

html

```
<button onClick = "IncTHR()">Increase Throttle</button>
<button onClick = "DecTHR()">Decrease Throttle</button>
<input type="text" id="THR">

<div id="CoolantTemp1"></p>
```

javascript

```
var CoolantTemp1 = 366;
var Throttle = 5;
var ControlRodHeight = 50;
var PrimaryPump = 1;

function IncTHR(){
user = ++Throttle;
    if (Throttle > 10){
    Throttle = 10;
    }
    CoolantTemp1 = (220+(ControlRodHeight*2.2)+(PrimaryPump*20)+(Throttle*3.2));
update();
displayResults();

function DecTHR(){
user = --Throttle;
    if (Throttle < 0){
    Throttle = 0;
    }
    CoolantTemp1 = (220+(ControlRodHeight*2.2)+(PrimaryPump*20)+(Throttle*3.2));
update();
displayResults();

function update() {
    document.getElementById("THR").value = Throttle;
}

function displayResults() {
    document.getElementById("CoolantTemp1").innerHTML = "Coolant Temperature 1 is " + CoolantTemp1;
}
```

So currently, as soon as the user clicks either throttle button, the Coolant Temperature is updated immediately to the solution - is there a way for the output to cycle through from the number it previously was to the new number it will become as a result of the calculation change?

Hope that makes sense!

Thank you.

Comment: If 5 = 366 and 6 = 369.2 by what amount to you want it to cycle? do you want to see 366, 367, 368, 369, 369.2 or by smaller amounts? How long do you want the change to take?

Comment: Hi Simon, thanks for your comment.  Whole numbers would be fine - and I wouldn't want the change to take too long, but long enough for the user to notice the numbers changing.  Approximately 1 second per number for small changes such as this would be ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
var CoolantTemp1 = 366;
var tempCounter = 366;
var Throttle = 5;
var ControlRodHeight = 50;
var PrimaryPump = 1;

function IncTHR(){
    Throttle++;
    if (Throttle > 10){
        Throttle = 10;
    }
    CoolantTemp1 = (220+(ControlRodHeight*2.2)+(PrimaryPump*20)+(Throttle*3.2));
    update();

    var incInt = setInterval(function (){
        if (tempCounter < CoolantTemp1){
            displayResults(tempCounter);
            tempCounter++;
        } else {
            displayResults(CoolantTemp1);
            tempCounter = CoolantTemp1;
            clearInterval(incInt);
        }
    }, 1000);

}

function DecTHR(){
    Throttle--;
    if (Throttle < 0){
        Throttle = 0;
    }
    CoolantTemp1 = (220+(ControlRodHeight*2.2)+(PrimaryPump*20)+(Throttle*3.2));
    update();

    var decInt = setInterval(function (){
        if (tempCounter > CoolantTemp1){
            displayResults(tempCounter);
            tempCounter--;
        } else {
            displayResults(CoolantTemp1);
            tempCounter = CoolantTemp1;
            clearInterval(decInt);
        }
    }, 1000);
}

function update() {
    document.getElementById("THR").value = Throttle;
}

function displayResults(temp) {
    document.getElementById("CoolantTemp1").innerHTML = "Coolant Temperature 1 is " + temp;
}
```

Comment: Hi Simon, thanks very much for your answer.  Do you know what I would do if I now want to expand this, and have the same for Coolant Temperature 2 and other variables?  Is tempCounter something I can add numbers to to differentiate for different variables? Thank you, Deborah.

Comment: You would need different variables for each counter so that they do not interfere with each other. You can use numbers like tempCounter1, tempCounter2 etc. you may prefer to give them more specific names so that when you come back to the code at a later date, things are clearer.